# MYSQL on lion - set root password

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

I just installed mysql in lion and am now trying to set the root password. I can get into mysql no problem by simply typing:

```
mysql
```

But when I try to get in as the root user which should let me in without issue as I have not set the root password yet by typing I get denied:

```
mysql -u root
```

Error:

connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

I have done plenty of searches on this issue but none have solved the problem. I am just denied no matter what as if there is a password set... I did have an installation of XAMPP installed earlier that I just deleted where I set the root password but I can't imagine there would be any conflict between the two installations... expecially since the XAMPP version has been deleted anyway. I have tried default creds like -u root -p root.

Why is this so difficult to do. I'd like to get on with my training. WTF

Comment: Have you tried `mysql -u root -p` and then hitting Enter?

Comment: yes. It prompts me for a password. I hit enter again as there shouldn't be a pass set but I get the same error. There seems to be a pass set but I don't know what it is...?

Comment: I had a similar issue in linux but not in OSX Lion, so maybe this will help: first start the service `mysqld` like `service mysqld start`, then try running `mysql_secure_installation`. It's supposed to setup the users database and other stuff, so you have a database to login into.

Comment: I am getting this: -bash: service: command not found when typing: service mysqld start ....?

Comment: Ok I ran the secure installation and I get this error: In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here. When I press enter I get the same access denied. should I remove mysql and try to reinstall or is there some sort of file that holds the credentials outside of mysql?

Comment: Worth a shot to reinstall, I don't think there even is a database of users set up at this point.

Comment: Yea just reinstalled same problem. There must be some sort of password set by the system or a file that was there previously. I know nothing about all this so I can't even speak intelligently about it. Anyone have an idea of what could be happening here?

Comment: A step I forgot to mention: have you installed `mysql-server` as well? Maybe after that you can start the `mysqld` service?

Comment: The same way you installed `mysql`? Using either `apt-get install mysql-server` or `yum install mysql-server` I suppose.

Comment: wow... I restarted the computer, turned off and on mysql and boom it worked...? strange... thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

As you mention that `mysql -u root -p` and `mysql_secure_installation` throw same error.So try to install `mysql-server` as

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```